# LyX undefined control sequence \input

Tags: tables, input, preamble

I'm a new user. I-m in trouble with lyX and in particular how to use `\input{file.tex}` correctly. Error: "undefined control sequence". Actually I'm not sure where I have to specify the path so that LyX can recognize and find it. So far I used Insert > float > table (here is where I'm going to append 2 different tables). In LateX preamble (Document > Settings > LateX Preamble) I'm using the following:

```
% Packages for tables
\usepackage{booktabs}% Pretty tables
\usepackage{threeparttablex}% For Notes below table

% *****************************************************************
% siunitx
% *****************************************************************
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}} 

\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-symbols           = ( ) [ ] - +,
        table-align-text-post   = false,
        input-signs             = ,
        }   

% Character substitution that prints brackets and the minus symbol in text mode. Thanks to David Carlisle
\def\yyy{%
  \bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string-%
  \uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\llap{\textendash}\relax}}}%
  \mathcode\expandafter`\string-"8000 }

\def\xxxl#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\llap{\string#1}}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }

\def\xxxr#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\rlap{\string#1}}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }

\def\textsymbols{\xxxl[\xxxr]\xxxl(\xxxr)\yyy}


% *****************************************************************
% Estout related things
% *****************************************************************
\let\estinput=\input % define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document

\newcommand{\estwide}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            \textsymbols% Note the added command here
            \begin{tabular*}
            {\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular*}
            }
        }   

\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            \textsymbols% Note the added command here
            \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular}
            }
        }

% Allow line breaks with \\ in specialcells
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}

% *****************************************************************
% Custom subcaptions
% *****************************************************************
% Note/Source/Text after Tables
% The new approach using threeparttables to generate notes that are the exact width of the table.
\newcommand{\Figtext}[1]{%
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    \hspace{6pt}
    \hangindent=1.75em
    #1
    \end{tablenotes}
    }
\newcommand{\Fignote}[1]{\Figtext{\emph{Note:~}~#1}}
\newcommand{\Figsource}[1]{\Figtext{\emph{Source:~}~#1}}
\newcommand{\Starnote}{\Figtext{* p < 0.1, ** p < 0.05, *** p < 0.01. Standard errors in parentheses.}}% Add significance note with \starnote
```

I appreciate your support! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. You seem to be missing `\documentclass{}` e.g. `\documentclass{article}` which should come before the first `\usepackage...` command. EDIT: Or is this hidden in Lyx?

Comment: @cfr The above is not the entire preamble, only the part the user has control over in LyX. The `\documentclass` and more is sort of hidden, yes.

Comment: user46589: I doubt that `\input` is undefined, are you sure about that? Could you create a minimal example (i.e. remove as much as possible from (a copy of) your document without removing the error), export it to LaTeX, and edit your question to include the LaTeX source?

Comment: I think \input just do not recognize the path. Moving the files seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The command `\input{}` should work in a new LyX file without user preamble as well as with your preample. Try this in the body of the document:

1. `Ctrl+L` (This make an ERT - evil red text - box)
2. Write inside the ERT box `\input{/your/path/here/file}` (you can omit the `.tex` extension)  or simply `\input{file}`  when the children document is in the same directory that the main document.

You can obtain the same result with the menu in `Insert > File > Children 
document` (or some like that, I cannot check the exact English labels). The result is the same, the only difference is that instead LaTeX code that is just ignored by LyX, you will see a clickable gray box that can be changed trough a Lyx window:

[image: MWE]

If you have an  "undefined control sequence" error it should be due to some offending command in the children document. Note that `file.tex` must be only a chunk of the document body, not a complete LaTeX document. First check that `\input{}` work fine with some plain tex (a "`Hello, Word!`"  is enough) or a simple table like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
    11 & 12 & 13\\
    21 & 22 & 23\\
    31 & 32 & 33\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```